# why does this quote fails my bash script?

Tags: bash

I am trying to save some typing with this bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

n=$(($#-1))
files=${@:1:$n}
dest=${!#}
echo "$n files"
echo "${files[@]}"
echo "$dest"
rsync -av "${files[@]}" kyopti:$dest
```

Notice the `"${files[@]}"` part, I did this because it's recommended on Greg's bash tutorial. This generates an error:

```
rsync: link_stat "/tmp/scplot.pdf ssknplot.pdf" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

But if I remove the quotes, everything works fine. I am confused, isn't this supposed to be the best practice, to add the quotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`files` is not an array. It's just a single string consisting of a space-separated list of the positional arguments. You want

```
files=( "${@:1:$n}" )
```

Then your quoted use of `files` in the `rsync` command will work as expected.